# Ignoring a substring/linebreak character in CLI arguments using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm using the argparse module in Python for the first time, and I haven't touched the language in over a year.
I need to solve a bug in a todo list where, if a new task is inputted with a line break, it creates two entries instead of one, e.g.:

```
$ python todo.py add "Hello,
World!"
```

will create entries:

```
0 Hello,
1 World!
```

Is there a way I can tell argparse to ignore the line break? I have tried looking into the documentation, but couldn't find it.

Comment: The `sys.argv` that the parser gets is `['todo.py', 'add', 'Hello,\nWorld']`.  `argparse` just puts that last string in the `args.add` attribute.  The line break is part of the string.  If you don't like it, remove it yourself after parsing.  That's not something you tell `argparse` to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove every newline from the arguments then pass them to `parse_args` or `parse_known_args`:

```
ArgumentParser.parse_args([arg.replace("\n", "") for arg in sys.argv[1:]])
```

As `ArgumentParser` uses `sys.argv` by default (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0924b95f6e678beaf4a059d679515956bac608fb/Lib/argparse.py#L1870), you could also modify `sys.argv` before the parsing, in the same way:

```
sys.argv = sys.argv[0] + [arg.replace("\n", "") for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
ArgumentParser.parse_args()
```

Or, still, you could override `parse_known_args`, as that is where the parsing is done.